# Netbeans php project debug breakpoints not working

Tags: netbeans, xdebug, breakpoints

On windows 10, Wamp PHP, Netbeans 8.1 and X-Debug (I believe), breakpoints don't work when selecting the debug project menu option but they do when debugging a file within the project (CakePHP).

Setting a breakpoint then selecting menu option "debug->debug project" starts a debug session, runs the project but no breakpoints work. Restarting the debugger with menu option "debug->debug file" will not run the application properly because it's the wrong place to start, but refreshing the web page stops correctly at the breakpoint.

Edit: a different test project works ok.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you already checked all the usual suspects: XDebug installed and configured.

1. Make sure that Web Root folder is selected under the project.
2. (if remote server used) Make sure that code on the server is identical to the one in Netbeans. (In rare case that something was edited on the server and not in netbeans)